# Android and Mysql problems

Tags: android, mysql

I need make a query with "Substring" but I don't know how to write it properly.

I have this query

```
String where2 = SUBSTRING(DatabaseHelper.DATE,0,4) + "=" + "'" + year + "'";

cursor = db.query("PRODUCT", FROM, where2, null, null, null, orderBy);
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: What goes wrong? You need to be more descriptive.

Comment: ANDROID thinks substring is a class and I must do this class. But It doesn't.

Comment: sorry, my English isn't good

Comment: I'm not sure I understand still :) Are you saying that you have to create the class/method?

Comment: Yes, the method  "SUBSTRING" isn't accepted. How I can do?.
I want to do a Substring, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method of the `String` class. In your case, this would look something like this:

```
String where2 = DatabaseHelper.DATE.subString(0, 4) + "=" + "'" + year + "'";
cursor = db.query("PRODUCT", FROM, where2, null, null, null, orderBy);
```

I'm assuming DatabaseHelper.DATE refers to a `String`.

**EDIT:**

You were referring to a substring method in SQLite, use the `substr(X,Y,Z)` method of the core functions. You can check it out in this list: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Your `where2` string would look like this then:

```
String where2 = "substr(" + DatabaseHelper.DATE + ", 0, 5) ='" + year + "'";
```

You might want to alias that column also, as the result will return a column with a name like `substr` or something. You can do that like this this:

```
String where2 = "substr(" + DatabaseHelper.DATE + ", 0, 5) ='" + year + "' AS mycolumn";
```

Comment: That would be fine if the sentence was executed on Android, but if you look the "where" clause for the sentence will be executed in mysql, so   doesn't work. Because I will have a error in mysql. I need do a substring in mysql without do a class in Android.

I don't know how mix the two things.

Comment: YEAHHHHHH!!!!!! great. I could kiss you if you were by my side. jejejeje. thanks a lot.

Comment: I suppose if I want to do any method of mysql. must to be in quotes. does that is right? . 
I need transform the substring result in Integer for later compare with a integer. because of this my question.

Comment: Glad I could help! And that's right, the methods needs to be inside the quotes since the String is a part of the SQL query itself. I'm not sure I understand your second question,  do you need to convert the result from the Cursor to an Integer?

Comment: I need transform day 05 for example in Integer, because when I do a substring of date, the result is string, and I want compare this result with a Integer.
for example 

today is 24/05/2013 and I have a column with a old date 23/05/2013

I do the substring the old date and I take 23 later I take the day of present date and I compare

is 23 minus 25. yes... then I do ... 
is 23 minus 25. no... then I do ...

Comment: Ok! I have solution: I done this:
String where2 = "CAST(substr("+DatabaseHelper.DATE+",1,4) AS INTEGER)"+ "="  +"CAST("+ year + " AS INTEGER)";

Thanks for all